# Laravel. Получение url

Tags: php, laravel

Как получить `url` в `laravel`?

Делаю следующую инструкцию:

1. Подключаю helper

   ```
   use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
   ```
2. Вывожу `$url = Request::url();`

Выводит ошибку:

> Cannot use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as Controller because the
>   name is already in use

Answer (score 2):

У вас уже использовано имя `Controller`

Request это фасад и правильно вызывать его так

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller {


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request::url();

        //
    }

}
```